# Calculating turnaround time for SJF and Round Robin

Tags: time, cpu, scheduling

I'm a little stumped here. I'm supposed to calculate turnaround time for SFJ (non-preemptive) and Round Robin quantums 1 and 10. I'm trying to go over some notes from the web, but I'm not really seem to grasping it. Can anyone easily explain how I can find turnaround time for SJF and RR Q 1 and 10 for the following table?

```
Process Arrival Time    Burst Time

P1          3.0         3.0

P2          2.0         7.0

P3          1.0         2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

we find the Gantt chart first.

| P3  |  P1  |  P2     |

1-----3-----6---------13

at 2.0 (millisecond i guess...) P2 came and P1 came at 3.0 ms .It's non preemptive so CPU was not preempted while executing any process , then the process with smallest burst time is chosen.

Average waiting time = [(1-1)+(6-2)+(3-3)]/3 = 1.33 ms

Average Turnaround time = [(0+2) + (7+4) + (3+0)]/3 = 5.33 ms

Answer (score 0):

Arrival time is the response time, in other words the time it takes to start the process. You should explain what you mean by Burst time... When counting scheduler times, I know of response/arrival, turnaround time, and wait time. Never heard of "Burst".